# Is there a clean way in Python to convert list or single element to specific format?

Tags: python, list, numpy, math, floating-point

I have a config file, in which items can be single element or list.

```
pct_accepted=0.75
pct_rejected=0.35, 0.5
```

Upon reading back, they will all be in string,

```
config['pct_accepted']='0.75'
config['pct_rejected']=['0.35', '0.5']
```

Is there a clean method of converted them to float other than having to check whether they are scalar or list 
My attempt for now is :

```
for k in ['pct_accepted','pct_rejected']:
   if isinstance(config[k], list) :
      config[k]=[float(item) for item in config[k]]
   if isinstance(config[k], string) :
      config[k]=float(config[k])
```

Doesn't look so neat.

Comment: The way you're doing it is perfectly find and readable. You could use `try` and `except`, but it would have the same general flow. For a "one-liner", you could use a ternary conditional + list comprehension but I think what you have is preferable.

Comment: could you elaborate ? don't we still need two different ways to convert two types even with __try__ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you included the `numpy` tag:

```
In [161]: np.array('12.23',float).tolist()                                                                   
Out[161]: 12.23
In [162]: np.array(['12.23','12.23'],float).tolist()                                                         
Out[162]: [12.23, 12.23]
```

short, sweet and overkill!

Comment: I also remembered there should be something on numpy. The catch is that **numpy float** type does not play well with native **float** type, and more than often some exception will throw somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's no clean way, simply because the conversion is not valid on a list: *something* has to look at the data type.  You can hide that in a function, but it's still there.

You *can* shorten the code a bit by using the available broadcast routines.  Something such as `map(float, config[k])` will perhaps make it look a little better to you.

You can also store the type in a variable, and test the variable twice, rather than using two `isinstance` calls.  This saves a few characters, and doesn't scale well, but it works nicely for simple applications.